# php DateTime() returning current date when assigning date in past

Tags: php, datetime, format, diff

I need to display the duration between the reported date / time and the time date / now. eg. 1 days 15 hours 48 mins

```
$reported = the_sub_field('reported'); //format eg. 27 January, 2020 12:00

$currdt= new DateTime(Date("Y-m-d H:i"));
var_dump($currdt);

$reporteddt= new DateTime($reported );
var_dump($reporteddt);

$interval = $currdt->diff($reporteddt);
var_dump($interval);

$duration =  $interval->d ." days ".$interval->h ." hours ". $interval->i ." mins";
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the comma.

```
$reported = '28 January, 2020 12:00'; 
$reported = str_replace(',', '', $reported);
$reporteddt= new DateTime($reported);
var_dump($reporteddt);
```

[Test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4322d9fb65fda2a57d3383d08782f9a854747d62)

Comment: That works great when the reported date is added direty to the variable, so there must be some issue with the date coming from wordpress ACF field ie.  $reported = the_sub_field('reported');  Thanks for your help, at least I know where the error lies now.